# Click link to show div inside container

Tags: jquery

I have multiple containers(li). Inside there are links. When clicked they need to open a matching div (and hide the non-matching divs).

I can loop through the divs but are unable to open or hide them.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/warddem/pen/kkzrPx

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3>Market study</h3>
    <div>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="#div1" class="showSingle">Results</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="#div2" class="showSingle">Learned</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="#div3" class="showSingle">Deliverables</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="#close" class="">Close all</a>
      <div id="div1" class="optionDiv">Results: </div>
      <div id="div2" class="optionDiv">Learned: </div>
      <div id="div3" class="optionDiv">Deliverables: </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>Competitive research</h3>
    <div>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="#div1" class="showSingle">Results</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="#div2" class="showSingle">Learned</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="#div3" class="showSingle">Deliverables</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="#close" class="">Close all</a>
      <div id="div1" class="optionDiv">Results: </div>
      <div id="div2" class="optionDiv">Learned: </div>
      <div id="div3" class="optionDiv">Deliverables: </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

jQuery('.showSingle').click(function() {

    var idOpen = $(this).siblings("div");
    var myIndex = $(this).index();

    if (idOpen.is("div")) {
      // HIDE ALL DIVS IN PARENT
      var divLength = idOpen.get(myIndex).id.length;
      for (var i = 0, l = divLength; i < l; i++) {
        console.log('divs to hide', idOpen[i]);
        //HIDE DOESN'T WORK
        //idOpen[i].hide();
      }

      // HOW TO SHOW LINKED DIV ???
      console.log('div id to open: ', idOpen.get(myIndex).id);
    }

  })
```

Comment: Id's must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start off with making the id's unique. (Though this doesn't seem relevant to the problem you're having.)

[`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) returns the element as an element. jQuery functions don't chain on these. [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) returns the element as part of a new jQuery object.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3>Market study</h3>
    <div>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="#div1a" class="showSingle">Results</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="#div2a" class="showSingle">Learned</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="#div3a" class="showSingle">Deliverables</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="#close" class="">Close all</a>
      <div id="div1a" class="optionDiv">Results: </div>
      <div id="div2a" class="optionDiv">Learned: </div>
      <div id="div3a" class="optionDiv">Deliverables: </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>Competitive research</h3>
    <div>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="#div1b" class="showSingle">Results</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="#div2b" class="showSingle">Learned</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="#div3b" class="showSingle">Deliverables</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="#close" class="">Close all</a>
      <div id="div1b" class="optionDiv">Results: </div>
      <div id="div2b" class="optionDiv">Learned: </div>
      <div id="div3b" class="optionDiv">Deliverables: </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
jQuery('.showSingle').click(function() {

    var idOpen = $(this).siblings("div");
    var myIndex = $(this).index();

    if (idOpen.is("div")) {
      // HIDE ALL DIVS IN PARENT
      var divLength = idOpen.get(myIndex).id.length;
      for (var i = 0, l = divLength; i < l; i++) {
        console.log('divs to hide', idOpen[i]);
        //HIDE DOESN'T WORK
        idOpen.eq(i).hide();
      }

      // HOW TO SHOW LINKED DIV ???
      idOpen.eq(myIndex).show();
      console.log('div id to open: ', idOpen.get(myIndex));
    }

  });
```

Comment: +1 for go with the index of `a` elements ... but no need to do that for loop .... here is a short version https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RGEArL

Comment: @DaniP Yeah, there are definitely clearer ways to do this kind of thing. I went for minimal changes in the original code so as not to confuse things.

Comment: Works perfect, thanks for your help. @DaniP great codepen, clean and easy. Very nice that I do not have to make unique ideas like that (faster to copy and paste sections. Thanks for the great help.

Comment: We are glad to help U @WarddeMuynck please mark this question as solved this is the right answer

Comment: @WarddeMuynck at the left side of this answer where you can se the votes for the answer below he number it's a gray check mark you can turn it to green by clicking on it on the answer you think is the right one or the one that help U